# ASP.NET intranet site asking for credentials - Windows Authentication

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, windows-server-2008, windows-authentication, credentials

I created my first website in ASP.Net and I am trying to get it up and running on our intranet here at work. I have got almost everything completed now, and I have come to a roadblock.

I need to use Windows Authentication - requirement from my team - so I went through the process of setting up the site. I have everything configured and attempted to access the site (non-localhost) and got a dialog box asking for my login credentials. I cannot figure out for the life of me why that is. I have made sure that IE8 is set to pass credentials, I have ensured that Windows Auth is set up in both my web.config file and on the server. as soon as i enter my windows login information, i get into the site without issue.

When i initially set up the page, I selected pass-through authentication and tested the connection. During that test, i got an error back saying that access to the path of the website could not be verified. This is my only guess, but unable to figure out a fix for it.

I thank you in advance for your help and am happy to answer any questions as soon as I see them posted. Again, I am just trying to get around having that dialog box pop up.

Comment: Is the server on the same network as the client?

Comment: Is your domain in the Intranet or Trusted Sites zones in IE?

Comment: The server is on the same network yes, but the domain is most likely not in a list of Trusted Sites.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add the site to your trusted sites in IE.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Our IT group has removed the Secruity tab in our version of IE8 so I can't do this myself. I have put in a request to IT to do it for the whole company. I will post if the issue persists.

Comment: This worked like a charm. Not sure why it wasn't set up initially but they added the server and now everything is working great.

Comment: Glad I could help, I ran into the same issues with a silverlight app I built for our local intranet.

Comment: The trusted sites solution did not work for me in either IE 8 or IE 9.  I suspect a difference in configuration though.  What did work for me was to add the site to my local intranet zone.  There is a security setting that says only allow auto login in the intranet zone (very bottom of Custom Level options).

Comment: Thank you Prof Von Lemongiggle for your comment. It was the answer for my domain as well.

Answer (score 4):

You need to make sure that "Integrated Windows Authentication" is setup on the site (and in IIS), other wise it won't take their login credentials and pass through.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754628(WS.10).aspx

http://codesnip.net/iis7-integrated-windows-authentication-win-2008

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I have already done this process (noted above) and have added the required xml to the web.config file and added it to IIS as well. Still no dice. I did look for this information for some time though and the website you provide above could have saved me hours of searching a few days ago!