# How to get IIS 7 Pass-Through Authentication to work

Tags: c#, authentication, iis

Similar questions have been asked, but none seem to answer what I'm looking for. I simply want a user's windows credentials to "pass-through" to my application so users logged into the domain don't have to retype their username and password just to use my application. The users should not be prompted at all!

When I run my app from Visual Studio I don't need to log in and the app is able to determine my user credentials, however when I browse the site from IIS I am asked to enter my user name and password.

I've set IIS authorization to allow all users. Authentication is set to Windows Authentication only, with provider set to NTLM only. The advanced settings Physical Path Credentials are set to "Application user (pass-through authentication)"

My app config looks like this:

```
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
    <authentication mode="Windows" />
    <authorization>
      <deny users="?" />
    </authorization>
  </system.web>
```

I'm fairly new at configuring IIS so please be as specific as possible.

Comment: Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9232546/asp-net-intranet-site-asking-for-credentials-windows-authentication. Basically, you have to instruct the client computers that the website is expecting authentication.

Comment: I added the site to my trusted sites... no luck. I still get asked to log in over and over.

Comment: That's not "pass through", but pre authentication.